# How to Change the message from policykit authentication agent?

Tags: policykit

In Policykit the  LocalAuthority component checks whether the action requested from PolicyKit is allowed.

Its decision takes into account the user accounts and groups that exist locally on the computer. If a password entry is needed, PolicyKit calls an authentication agent. This agent basically consists of an input mask.

[image]

So I need to change the message "System policy prevents setting ..blah blah blah.. this action" from the authentication agent.

I've tried editing the XML file of the policy in the `/usr/share/polkit-1/action/POLICYNAME`. Then search for the tag in the XML file named message and edit there. I did that but nothing have changed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the *"System policy prevents setting proxy settings"* message in those .xml files just as you said.

You cannot simply change the *"An application is attempting ... this action."* message because that message is hardcoded into the gnome authentication agent. [source code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/saucy/policykit-1-gnome/saucy/view/head:/src/polkitgnomeauthenticationdialog.c). You have to modify the source code and recompile the gnome authentication agent for yourself if you want to change that message.

Comment: +1 for answering even that its the same result of what i have tried.. I'll wait while if nobody has other solution i'm gonna mark it as answer